# Authorization for GET request Python and .NET

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x, .net

I am trying to get some data from a database but it requires an HMAC authorization. The documentation is in .net and js and it is hard to translate to python. I do not have tons of experience with GET requests nor authorization. I think I got the hash to run successfully but I get 401 errors when trying to access the URL. I am provided a username and password and I think the password is used as the "secret key" in the hash.

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import datetime
import requests

url = 'URL GIVEN'
dt=datetime.datetime.now()
dt = (dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%m-%S"))


newhmac = hmac.new('PASSWORD GIVEN'.encode('ascii'), None, digestmod = hashlib.md5)

digest = newhmac.hexdigest()
    
print(digest)

HEADERS = {'Authorization':'{}:{}'.format(digest, dt)}
print(HEADERS)
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(HEADERS)
    print(s.headers)
    r = s.get(url)

print(r)
```

This is the code I have so far that gives me this

```
85b199b366bb319839d96629b75aa998
{'Authorization': 'USERNAME:85b199b366bb319839d96629b75aa998:2022-11-08T18-11-02'}
{'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.28.1', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'USERNAME:85b199b366bb319839d96629b75aa998:2022-11-08T18-11-02'}
<Response [401]>
```

```
Sample .net code to produce hash:
Private Sub SignRequest(req As WebRequest, paramStr As String, ByVal ts As String)
Dim x As String = String.Format("{0}{1}", paramStr, ts)
Dim secretBytes As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_password)
Dim hmac As New HMACMD5(secretBytes)
Dim dataBytes As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(x)
Dim computedHash As Byte() = hmac.ComputeHash(dataBytes)
Dim computedHashString As String = Convert.ToBase64String(computedHash)
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", _Username & ":" & computedHashString & ":" & ts)
End Sub
```

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
const { username, password } = process.env;
const formatTimestampForHash = (d = new Date()) => {
const pad2 = (str) => String(str).padStart(2, '0');
const DD = pad2(d.getUTCDate());
const MM = pad2(d.getUTCMonth() + 1);
const YYYY = d.getUTCFullYear();
const hh = pad2(d.getUTCHours());
const mm = pad2(d.getUTCMinutes());
const ss = pad2(d.getUTCSeconds());
return `${DD}${MM}${YYYY}${hh}${mm}${ss}`;
}
const stripProtocolFromUrl = (url) => {
return url
.replace(/https|http/i, '')
.replace('://', '');
}
export const createAuthHash = (url) => {
const timeStamp = formatTimestampForHash();
const formattedUrl = `${stripProtocolFromUrl(url)}${timeStamp}`;
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacMD5(
formattedUrl,
password
).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
return `${username}:${hash}:${timeStamp}`;
}
```

This is the code the documentation provides. I have tried adding the username to the AUTH header like it shows and still get 401 errors. I think it might be a problem with my hash but I am not sure and can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are missing the username from the Authorization header. It should be `HEADERS = {'Authorization':'{}:{}:{}'.format(username, digest, dt)}`.

Comment: I should've mentioned that I had tried that. I had changed my code when I pasted this in. Still does not work but I appreciate your comment

Comment: Also, you need to specify a message when creating the HMAC: `newhmac = hmac.new('PASSWORD GIVEN'.encode('ascii'), "{}{}".format(param_str, dt).encode('ascii'), digestmod = hashlib.md5)`. You should check the documentation for the correct value of the .NET `paramStr` and the correct format of the timestamp.

Comment: @JackTaylor I know I have the correct timestamp format but I will try the param_str. Thank you

Comment: @JackTaylor I am a little confused because it seems like HMAC is used to encrypt a message which is what you are telling me to add. But the documentation I have provides no message to be encrypted. It seems to me like we are just hashing the password to get authorization. Is this correct or am wrong?

Comment: My documentation says this
`The hash is computed on the request URL {minus the protocol} plus a timestamp value.
The timestamp is formed using the current date and time in UTC. The authorization
header is then built by concatenating the user’s login id, the hash value, and timestamp
string. The three fields are separated by a colon character.`
Does that mean the url - the protocol would be the param_str? because that did not work either when I tried it